# Apache redirecting users to https keeping uri

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I'm configuring a Apache server, and trying to get it to redirect from http to https.

eg.

http://example.com/something/awesome/ -> http://www.example.com/something/awesome

my problem is the as long as i try to redirect within the http (not https) everything works, but as soon as i try redirecting from http to https i am losing my uri and it redirects to

https://www.example.com/ or https://www.example.com/index.php

So it's not preserving the path.

this is what i got right now:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTPS_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

unfortunately i have been messing so much around with it that i could fill out a book at this point.
hope somebody can give me a kick in the right direction.

**EDIT**

Just to add a little more information on the subject, it a drupal system and my rewrite rules look like this in the .htaccess

```
# Various rewrite rules.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTPS_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

  # Set "protossl" to "s" if we were accessed via https://.  This is used later
  # if you enable "www." stripping or enforcement, in order to ensure that
  # you don't bounce between http and https.
  #RewriteRule ^ - [E=protossl]
  #RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
  #RewriteRule ^ - [E=protossl:s]

  # Make sure Authorization HTTP header is available to PHP
  # even when running as CGI or FastCGI.
  RewriteRule ^ - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

  # Block access to "hidden" directories whose names begin with a period. This
  # includes directories used by version control systems such as Subversion or
  # Git to store control files. Files whose names begin with a period, as well
  # as the control files used by CVS, are protected by the FilesMatch directive
  # above.
  #
  # NOTE: This only works when mod_rewrite is loaded. Without mod_rewrite, it is
  # not possible to block access to entire directories from .htaccess, because
  # <DirectoryMatch> is not allowed here.
  #
  # If you do not have mod_rewrite installed, you should remove these
  # directories from your webroot or otherwise protect them from being
  # downloaded.
  RewriteRule "(^|/)\." - [F]

  # If your site can be accessed both with and without the 'www.' prefix, you
  # can use one of the following settings to redirect users to your preferred
  # URL, either WITH or WITHOUT the 'www.' prefix. Choose ONLY one option:
  #
  # To redirect all users to access the site WITH the 'www.' prefix,
  # (http://example.com/... will be redirected to http://www.example.com/...)
  # uncomment the following:

  #RewriteCond %{HTTPS_HOST} .
  #RewriteCond %{HTTPS_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
  #RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]


  #
  # To redirect all users to access the site WITHOUT the 'www.' prefix,
  # (http://www.example.com/... will be redirected to http://example.com/...)
  # uncomment the following:
  # RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
  # RewriteRule ^ http%{ENV:protossl}://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

  # Modify the RewriteBase if you are using Drupal in a subdirectory or in a
  # VirtualDocumentRoot and the rewrite rules are not working properly.
  # For example if your site is at http://example.com/drupal uncomment and
  # modify the following line:
  # RewriteBase /drupal
  #
  # If your site is running in a VirtualDocumentRoot at http://example.com/,
  # uncomment the following line:
  # RewriteBase /

  # Pass all requests not referring directly to files in the filesystem to
  # index.php. Clean URLs are handled in drupal_environment_initialize().
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
  RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

  # Rules to correctly serve gzip compressed CSS and JS files.
  # Requires both mod_rewrite and mod_headers to be enabled.
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    # Serve gzip compressed CSS files if they exist and the client accepts gzip.
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-encoding} gzip
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.gz -s
    RewriteRule ^(.*)\.css $1\.css\.gz [QSA]

    # Serve gzip compressed JS files if they exist and the client accepts gzip.
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-encoding} gzip
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.gz -s
    RewriteRule ^(.*)\.js $1\.js\.gz [QSA]

    # Serve correct content types, and prevent mod_deflate double gzip.
    RewriteRule \.css\.gz$ - [T=text/css,E=no-gzip:1]
    RewriteRule \.js\.gz$ - [T=text/javascript,E=no-gzip:1]

    <FilesMatch "(\.js\.gz|\.css\.gz)$">
      # Serve correct encoding type.
      Header set Content-Encoding gzip
      # Force proxies to cache gzipped & non-gzipped css/js files separately.
      Header append Vary Accept-Encoding
    </FilesMatch>
  </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Did you clear your browser's cache?

Comment: Yes, just checked again no fun in making that mistake ;)

Comment: Make sure above rule is very first rule just below `RewriteEngine` line and then clear your browser cache.

Comment: @anubhava - I just tried to change it as suggested, and i still can't get it to work, I don't know if it's a conflict in another part of the rewrite rules, so i have added a bit more information on the subject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your first rule below `RewriteEngine On` with this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTPS_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

Clear your browser cache and retest.

Comment: After fiddeling with it for a while, I removed the htaccess entirely, and added everything again and it worked. Thanks